# Объекты и бинарные файлы C++

Tags: c++, файлы, filestream, binary-file

Подскажите, как правильно читать (и писать) объекты в бинарный файл. Добавил два метода:

```
    void Foo::load(std::istream& istream);
    void Foo::save(std::ostream& ostream) const;
```

(Там внутри используется reinterpret_cast, что несколько смущает. Хотя, если это есть только внутри подобных методов, то, наверно, это нормально)

Далее, одни объекты могут включаться в другие объекты (с указанием типа и размера). И тут, с одной стороны, нужно, чтобы вложенный объект не пытался прочитать больше, чем нужно. А с другой, чтобы обработки этого объекта (в том числе, если мы его пропускаем и вообще не читаем) оказаться на нужной позиции в файле для обработки последующих данных. У меня получился вот такой монстр:

```
            uint32_t type;
            file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&type), 4);
            uint32_t len;
            file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&len), 4);
            std::string str;
            str.resize(len);
            vtxTile.read(str.data(), len);
            std::istringstream buf(str);
            if (type == Foo::_type) {
                Foo foo;
                foo.load(buf);
...
            }
```

Оно работает. Но это явно нужно делать как-то иначе.

И по записи аналогично - записать объект в буфер, записать в файл размер буфера, записать в файл сам буфер.

ЗЫ в объекте первое поле - id. В файле их подряд несколько штук, заранее не известно сколько. Признаком конца является -1 вместо id очередного объекта. Как такое прочитать? Сначала читать id, а потом, внутри load(), читать всё остальное? Как-то не очень. Внутри load(), если id меньше нуля, бросать исключение? Тоже как-то не очень.

Comment: А что насчет того чтобы использовать готовые библиотеки для сериализации объектов, например boost::serialization (или как она там называется)?

Comment: Может быть, в конечном итоге я воспользуюсь им. Но из академических соображений хотелось бы обойтись без него.

Comment: Попробуйте в json сериализовать, тоже много готовых библиотек под эту задачу есть.

Comment: @peter нет, нужны именно бинарные файлы. Собственно, программа пишется для уже существующих файлов.